# EF6 not populating property on Many to Many

Tags: .net, entity-framework

I have the following POCO classes defined which map Speakers to Themes in a many-to-many relationship:

```
public class Speaker
{
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Firstname { get; set; }
        public string Surname { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<SpeakerTalkTheme> TalkThemes { get;set; }
}

public class SpeakerTalkTheme
    {
        [Key, Column(Order = 0)]
        public int TalkThemeId { get; set; }

        [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
        public int SpeakerId { get; set; }

        public TalkTheme TalkTheme { get; set; }


        public Speaker Speaker { get; set; }
    }
}   

public class TalkTheme
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Theme { get; set; }

        public int Length { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<ThemeTag> ThemeTags { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<SpeakerTalkTheme> TalkThemes { get;set; }
    }
```

However, when I query the database and return from WebAPI like so:

```
 public class SpeakerController : ApiController
    {
        public IEnumerable<Speaker> Get()
        {
            var db = new MyDbContext();
            var model = db.Speakers.Include(x => x.TalkThemes).ToList();
            return model;
        }     
    }
```

I get NULL in the themes property (see below):

```
[
  {
    "TalkThemes": [
      {
        "TalkThemeId": 1,
        "SpeakerId": 1,
        "TalkTheme": null
      }
    ],
    "Id": 1,
    "Firstname": "Joe",
    "Surname": "Bloggs"
  }
]
```

Shouldn't the TalkTheme property be populated? Its currently just showing NULL and I have no idea how to get this populated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you need to load another level. Do the following in your `Include` call:

```
 //...
 var model = db.Speakers.Include(x => x.TalkThemes.Select(tt=>tt.TalkTheme )).ToList();
```

If you want to see more examples how to load several levels in a query, check the **Remarks** section in this [msdn page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg671236(v=vs.113).aspx).